# Saving to database with relationship data Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am learning about Laravel relationships and come across a little issue that I can't seem to work out.

Basically I have a Client and Address model with a one to one relationship. When creating a new client, I want to capture the address of that client but its optional.

When creating a new client and not inputting any address values, obviously a relationship will be created but with null entries.

Is it possible to create the client, check if the client has an address first and if not, don't create the relationship? Also, the same for the update method?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    // Create the client
    $client = Client::create($request->all());

    // Relate address   
    $address = new \App\Address($request->all());
    $client->address()->save($address);

    return redirect()
        ->route('clients.index');

}


public function update(Request $request, Client $client)
{

    // update the client
    $client->update($request->all());

    $address = [
        'address_1' => $request->address_1,
        'address_2' => $request->address_2,
        'address_3' => $request->address_3,
        'city' => $request->city,
        'postcode' => $request->postcode,
    ];

    // update the address
    $client->address()->updateOrCreate($address);

    return redirect()->route('clients.index');

}
```

Also if there is any advice on better ways of going about this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{    
     // check if the address is not empty
     
    if (!empty($request->get('address')){

    // Create the client
    $client = Client::create($request->all());

    // Relate address   
    $client->address()->create($request->get('address'));

    return redirect()
        ->route('clients.index');
    }else{
     return back()->withError('Empty address');
    }

}
```

Comment: This still creates the relation if the address field is empty.